# weight paint on influence of maintain volume constraint

Tags: weight-painting, constraints

I'm trying to apply the maintain volume constraint on a part of an object.
So specifically, I want a part of a cube to keep its shape, and another part of that same cube to bulge out (as per maintain volume constraint) when the cube is compressed (scaled) along the z-axis.
I have made a vertex group of the part of the mesh that I want to be flexible, but constraints appear to only work on an object, not a mesh.
I have weight painted the region I want to be flexible, but I cannot seem to reference the influence of the constraint to the weight map.

edit:
I am aware that constraints are originally made for bones, but as I am working in version 3.6, it works fine on non-bone objects as well; see the little clip I made. This is a mesh cube with maintain volume constraint applied with the z-axis as only free axis. No bones involved here.
[image: maintain volume constraint on cube mesh, scaled on z-axis]

Comment: This is the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/transform/maintain_volume.html#maintain-volume-constraint) entry for that constraint. It looks as if it only works on a bone since it's only available on the bone modifier menu. There's an 8-message thread from 2010 about it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220702025853/http://www.harkyman.com/2010/03/16/maintaining-bone-volume-a-new-constraint/).

Comment: "I want a part of a cube to keep its shape, and another part" -- this is deformation, as opposed to transformation.  You cannot do it with object constraints.  You need to use deformation techniques instead.  Look into armature deformation.  You will likely be weighting the mesh to at least two bones, one of which may have a maintain volume constraint; you will transform the bones, in pose mode, rather than directly doing anything to the cube.